# distance between regression models

Tags: regression, correlation, linear-algebra, function

Consider two multivariate linear regression models (vector inputs and outputs) with the same domain observations.  Namely, let:

- $X \in \mathcal{R}^{a \times N}$ be a matrix of domain observations (design matrix)
- $Y_i \in \mathcal{R}^{b \times N_i}$ be one (of two) co-domain observations matrices

where corresponding columns of $X$ and $Y_i$ refer to paired vector observations.  One can find the matrix, $\beta_i$, which maps each observation in $X$ to $Y_i$ as $y = \beta x$ while minimizing the mean squared error as $\beta_i = Y_i X^+$ where $X^+$ is the right pseudo-inverse of $X$.

Is there a natural metric between these two regression models?

I'm looking for something which captures the covariances in $Y_i$ (so metrics on $\beta$ directly, the space of mappings from $X$ to $Y$, don't fit the bill since $\beta_0 = \beta_1$ does not imply $Y_0 = Y_1$.)

Comment: The F-stat feels as if its lurking but it also doesn't quite fit, its a measure between two models with two distinct domains, $X_0, X_1$ and a constant $Y$

Comment: Maybe you want to compare $R^2$ values? The multivariate bootstrap comes to mind. Also the logit transformation or something similar to lessen the problems of bounded scale.

Answer (score 2):

A model is really just a distribution;$^\dagger$ you can measure the distances between $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ (or rather, their distributions) via metrics like [statistical distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance). For example, [f-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) (which encompass the total variation *distance*, squared Hellinger *distance*, and Kullback-Leibler *divergence*).

$^\dagger$By that I mean $Y_{0, i} | X_i \sim \text{Normal}_i$ for $i \in 1, 2, \dots, n$ where $n$ is the number of observations you have. Same goes for $Y_1, i | X_i$.

References:

- Example on how to [compute the Hellinger distance for Gaussian distributions](https://web.archive.org/web/20210518083040/https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2020/01/22/about-the-hellinger-distance/)
- Quick tutorial on [Monte Carlo integration](https://web.archive.org/web/20170712154611/https://theclevermachine.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/monte-carlo-approximations/) (use it to approximate expectations, e.g., in this case, f-divergences.)

Comment: One concern I have is that I don't have distributions exactly, just a set of observations.  Or maybe I'm just not understanding precisely what you mean with "a model is really just a distribution".  (and thank you!)

Comment: @eretmochelys I updated the answer to address your follow-up questions. Let me know if it's still unclear. (You're welcome!)

Comment: quick note for other readers (things I didn't get right away): this does meet my goal of not just comparing betas because the normal distributions have covariances estimated by the  residuals of each model.

Comment: @eretmochelys awesome! Hope it helped. Welcome to CVSE!

Answer (score 0):

The [F-stat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Regression_problems) contains a ratio which describes the increased error in going from a full model to the reduced model ("reduced" because it has a subset of explanatory $x$ variables so its average residuals are not smaller).  In a similar spirit, we could measure model similarity by examining the increase in error in swapping the betas (i.e. applying $\beta_0$ to $Y_1$ and $\beta_1$ to $Y_0$).

Let the residual matrix of data i under model j be:

$\mathcal{E}_{i|j} = \beta_j X - Y_i$

we can compute the mean squared error of these as:

$MSE_{i|j} = \frac{1}{N_i} Tr (\mathcal{E}_{i|j}\mathcal{E}_{i|j}^T)$

so that the "swapped increase in mse" is:

$\frac{MSE' - MSE}{MSE}$

where $MSE' = MSE_{0|1} + MSE_{1|0}$ is the swapped mean square error and $MSE = MSE_{0|0} + MSE_{1|1}$ is the original mean square error.